# Cannot Allocate Memory Error in Python for PIPE usage in loop?

Tags: python, openssl, subprocess, pipe, popen

I'm trying to execute openssl command to generate encrypted key using python script. To execute linux commands I have used `subprocess.Popen()` and PIPE for std operations. My code implementation has threads internally which calls subprocess calls for around 10 threads. Please help me with this.

```
start_threads():
    no_of_threads =10
    threads_limit=5
    for iteration in range(no_of_threads)
        threads_limit=threadd_limit
        t=threading.Thread(self.do_generate, args=(threads_limit))
        t.start()
        
do_generate(threads_limit):
    for i in range(threads_limit):
        p=subprocess.Popen("openssl rand -hex 400 | tr -dc 'b-f13-8 | head -c40'", stdin=subprocess.PIPE,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,shell=True)
        output,err=p.communicate()
```

What I'm suspecting is that, this memory is being used by PIPE and not getting free after it's usage. I have tried with `kill()` etc and nothing worked for me.

Comment: Could you show us how you create the threads?

Comment: Hi @MihailFeraru updated sample code for launching threads